# using handleWebsocketMessage in akka-http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

Using akka-http, how can I construct a `Flow[Message, Message, _]`
to pass to`handleWebsocketMessage` that only listens to incoming data but does not write anything back? Is it possible to use a Sink in anyway? Because a Sink sounds like what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to create a `Flow` from independent `Source` and `Sink`, which is what you'll need here. To get more inside info about how it can word you may want to read the [stream composition](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/stream-composition.html) docs.

In general what you need is to create a Flow such that it is a Sink that can handle the incoming messages and a Source that never emits, this is achieved by:

```
Flow.wrap(Sink.foreach(println), Source.lazyEmpty)(Keep.none)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this gives me an error since wrap has either 3 or 5 type parameters. I looked at the source https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/release-2.3-dev/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.scala#L335. But I don't really understand what the third type should be.

Comment: Thanks again, but the only parameter should actually be a graph. "def wrap[I, O, M](g: Graph[FlowShape[I, O], M]): Flow[I, O, M]" How do I create that or if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Flow.wrap(Sink.foreach(println), Source.lazyEmpty)(Keep.none) finally worked.

Comment: A `Flow[In, Out, M]` IS-A `Graph[FlowShape[In, Out], M]` :-) All types of Flows/Sinks/Sources/anything are graphs actually, we have unified them all as such.